# ASP.net MVC 5 partial view Ajax POST not updating just the partial

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that is not updating just the partial, it redirects to the action for the entire page.

In the partial view, _registerAccount.cshtml, that contains a post request to register, the request is made via Ajax in a view named _registerAccount as so:

```
@model LoginDemo.Models.LdapAccountModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterLdapAccount", "Account", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Email) @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Email, new { id = "reg-ytu-email" })
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Password) @Html.PasswordFor(x => Model.Password, new { id = "reg-pw" })
    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn" />
}
```

In the parent page, Register.cshtml I have:

```
@model LoginDemo.Models.RegisterModel
...            
<div class="panel hide register-type register-ytu">
  @Html.Partial("_registerAccount")
</div>
```

In the Account Controller the ajax request goes to the RegisterAccount action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterLdapAccount(LdapAccountModel model)
    {
        if (model.exists()) // pseudo code
        {
            return Json(new {foo: "bar"}); // return address to redirect to
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "You must have a valid account.");

            return PartialView(model); // return error
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that whatever gets returned wipes out the entire page as opposed to updating just the partial within the parent page. That is, if successful the JSON return only returns the JSON, if failed the partial view return only returns the partial.

n.b. I have `<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` in my web.config.

Comment: are you missing `UpdateTargetId`?

Comment: WHat happens if you include the name of the partial view in the controllers return? Like: `return PartialView("_PartialView", model)`?

Comment: Added both UpdateTargetID and the Partial view return as suggested - neither worked (together or independently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amend the following code as follows:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterLdapAccount", "Account", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "Post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "updatearea",
```

Amend the div to add the id:

```
<div id="updatearea" class="panel hide register-type register-ytu">
  @Html.Partial("_registerAccount")
</div>
```

Now make sure you have unobtrustive ajax as a script on the page if you don't already.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")"></script>
```

To add this script it must be in the scripts folder for your project.

Amend the controller so that you are loading the correct partial view, if you don't state the name of the partial view the partial view loaded will be whatever matches the name of the action, if no partial view matches the name of the action no partial view will be loaded.  So explicitly state which partial view you want to load like this:

return PartialView("_RegisterAccount", model)

Comment: Looks like it was the missing unobtrusive ajax causing part of the issue. Also moving the form out of the partial seems to have help. Thanks.